# Building HTMLQuestion XML for boto3 MTurk

Tags: xml, lxml, boto3, cdata

I'm trying to build XML to submit to Amazon's Mechanical Turks service using the HTMLQuestion data structure and boto3's [create_hit](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.create_hit) function. According to the documentation, the XML should be formatted [like this](https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/3d593c92249d54cc5a5f341b21a2e8bc).

I've created a class `TurkTaskAssembler` which has methods for generating the xml and passing this XML to the Mechanical Turks platform via API. I use the boto3 library to handle communication with Amazon.

It seems that the XML that I'm generating is formatted incorrectly, because when I attempt to pass this XML via the API, I get a validation error, like so:

```
>>> tta = TurkTaskAssembler("What color is the sky?")
>>> response = tta.create_hit_task()
>>> ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Question, value: <Element HTMLQuestion at 0x1135f68c0>, type: <type 'lxml.etree._Element'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

I then modified the `create_question_xml` method to convert the XML envelope to a string using the `tostring` method, but this generates a different error:

```
>>> tta = TurkTaskAssembler("What color is the sky?")
>>> tta.create_hit_task()
>>> ClientError: An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the CreateHIT operation: There was an error parsing the XML question or answer data in your request.  Please make sure the data is well-formed and validates against the appropriate schema. Details: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'HTMLQuestion'. (1508611228659 s)
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong and have very little XML experience.

Here is all of the relevant code:

```
import os
import boto3
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, CDATA, tostring
from .settings import mturk_access_key_id, mturk_access_secret_key

xml_schema_url = 'http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd'


class TurkTaskAssembler(object):

    def __init__(self, question):
        self.client = boto3.client(
            service_name='mturk',
            region_name='us-east-1',
            endpoint_url='https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
            aws_access_key_id=mturk_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=mturk_access_secret_key
        )
        self.question = question

    def create_question_xml(self):
        # questionFile = open(os.path.join(__location__, "question.xml"), "r")
        # question = questionFile.read()
        # return question
        XHTML_NAMESPACE = xml_schema_url
        XHTML = "{%s}" % XHTML_NAMESPACE
        NSMAP = {
            None : XHTML_NAMESPACE,
            'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
            ''
            }
        envelope = Element("HTMLQuestion", nsmap=NSMAP)

        html =  """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
             <head>
              <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
              <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
             </head>
             <body>
              <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
              <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
              <h1>Answer this question</h1>
              <p>{question}</p>
              <p><textarea name='comment' cols='80' rows='3'></textarea></p>
              <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>
              <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
             </body>
            </html>
            """.format(question=self.question)

        html_content = SubElement(envelope, 'HTMLContent')
        html_content.text = CDATA(html)
        xml_meta = """<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>"""
        return xml_meta + tostring(envelope, encoding='utf-8')

    def create_hit_task(self):
        response = self.client.create_hit(
            MaxAssignments=1,
            AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds=10800,
            LifetimeInSeconds=10800,
            AssignmentDurationInSeconds=300,
            Reward='0.05',
            Title='a title',
            Keywords='some keywords',
            Description='a description',
            Question=self.create_question_xml(),
        )
        return response
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply put the XML data inside a separate XML file (as you did, but commented out)? That would prevent you from having to incorporate several modules and a lot of code.

Using the template you described [here](https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/3d593c92249d54cc5a5f341b21a2e8bc), create `question.xml`:

```
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
  <h1>Answer this question</h1>
  <p>{question}</p>
  <p><textarea name='comment' cols='80' rows='3'></textarea></p>
  <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>
  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
 </body>
</html>
]]>
  </HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>450</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

Then in your `create_question_xml()` function:

```
def create_question_xml(self):
    question_file = open("question.xml", "r").read()
    xml = question_file.format(question=self.question)
    return xml
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you a bit confused with 3 formats Amazon suggests you to use. 
From what I see you went with [HTMLQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html). (Other two are: [ExternalQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) and [QuestionFormData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html)).

To keep question in `HTMLQuestion` format just use the plain example provided in documentation, no need to wrap it in XML. Here is a fixed function:

```
def create_question_html(self):
    # you can extract template into a file, 
    # as @Mangohero1 suggested which would simplify code a bit.

    return """
    <HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
      <HTMLContent><![CDATA[
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
      <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
      <h1>{question}</h1>
      <p><textarea name='comment' cols='80' rows='3'></textarea></p>
      <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>
      <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
     </body>
    </html>
    ]]>
      </HTMLContent>
      <FrameHeight>450</FrameHeight>
    </HTMLQuestion>
    """.format(question=self.question)
```